# How to get the Id value of <li> element js/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

My working code to send value the of `<option>` is

```
function getXhr() {
    var xhr = null; 
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // Firefox et autres
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){ // Internet Explorer 
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } else { // XMLHttpRequest non supporté par le navigateur 
        alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les objets XMLHTTPRequest..."); 
        xhr = false; 
    } 
    return xhr;
}

function go() {
    var xhr = getXhr();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            leselect = xhr.responseText;
            document.getElementById('modelecontainer').innerHTML = leselect;
        }
    }

    // Ici on va voir comment faire du post
    xhr.open("POST","contenu_a_charger.php",true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    sel = document.getElementById('vehicule');
    idmarque = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    xhr.send("idMarque="+idmarque);
}
```

I'm just trying to change the `sel` var of my previous code to have the Id value of `<li>`.

My `<li>` (from php loop)

```
<li id="7" onclick="go()">
    <span class="badge"><?php echo $FM->etat_user;?></span>
    <span class="head"><?php echo $FM->login_user;?></span>
</li>
```

My old working select

```
<select name="vehicule" id="pays" onchange="go()">
    <option value="0">Sélectionnez votre test</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
```

How do I get the Id of the `li` element ("7" in this example)?

Comment: vehicule is the name property, not the id

Comment: Capture the event in go, e.g go(e){}, then use it to get the element that clicked it, something like e.target.getAttribute('id')

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery? I see it's in the question tags, but I don't see you using it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry buddy, i click too fast on it, thank for your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ***jQuery*** (according to your question tags),
**All of your code can be simplified into just:**

```
$("#7").click(function() {
    $.post("contenu_a_charger.php", "idMarque=" + $(this).attr("id"), function(returnedData) {
        $("#modelecontainer").text(returnedData);
    });
});
```

That way you don't have to worry about any XHR objects or browser compatibility. It's all already part of the library. It also removes the need for you to put any event markup in your HTML, so you can remove the `onclick="go()"`.

**P.S.** When you assign a handler to a JavaScript event *from the JavaScript*, you can always just use `this` inside the handler in order to access the `event.srcElement`.
(ie use `this.id` to get the value of `7`)
For example: `document.getElementById("7").onclick = function() { alert(this.id); }`

Comment: Is `$(this).attr("id")` needed here? Should be `"7"`, right?

Comment: @AndersLindén Yes, but it's best to hard code as few things as possible in order to make the project easier to maintain. If they wanted to change the id to something else, all that has to change is the jQuery selector at the beginning.

Comment: It could also be easier to maintain the project if the code does not pretend that a certain value is not hardcoded. It will make the code shorter to write `"idMarque=7"` and will reveal the true nature of the it, also important when maintaining,

Comment: @AndersLindén True, but then this is only example code. It's pretty unlikely that `7` is the only element that needs this behavior in the real code. The selector can be broadened to more elements, and you don't have to create a different hard-coded handler for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
sel = document.getElementById('vehicule');
idmarque = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

into:

```
idmarque = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: Always say *why*. That way you can give a more intelligent answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a plain JavaScript solution, you could go with this: Given that you change your list element opening tag to this `<li id="7" onclick="go(event)">`, you can simply access the id in the `go` function like so:

```
function go(event){
    var id = event.target.id || event.target.parentNode.id;
}
```

Edit: Obviously this wouldn't work anymore if you nest further elements (as opposed to Anders solution). Assuming that you set the ID of your list element anyway, why don't you just do this:

```
<li id="7" onclick="go(7)">
  <span class="badge"><?php echo $FM->etat_user;?></span>
  <span class="head"><?php echo $FM->login_user;?></span>
</li>
```

And then you can access the ID as parameter of your function:

```
function go(id){
    var xhr = getXhr();
    // ....
}
```

Comment: They are using jQuery (see the question tags)

Comment: Well, I noticed the tag, but looking at the code there is not a single jQuery statement. I.e. XHR requests are manually opened, elements are selected using plain javascript such as `document.getElementById`, etc.

Comment: There's no need for adding a parameter for the event. Just use `this` while inside of the `go` method instead. It will refer to the `event.srcElement` by default.

Comment: Well, this is certainly true if you use jQuery like you did (because jQuery binds the execution context of the function to the triggering DOM element). The inline version, however, does not do this. `this` defaults to the global object (window) in this case.

Comment: No, it's also true of plain JS. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L9u0twa/) You just have to set the `onclick` property from the JS instead of from the HTML. (Which is what should already be done anyway for separation of concerns.)

Comment: I explicitly stretched the `inline` part. Your fiddle assigns the click handler in javascript, not inline. Here an adapted inline version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bywyo84w/1/ Note that `this` within the function is the `window` object.

Comment: If you want to use `this` inline, then do `onclick="go(this)"` instead. Then the parameter will already be the DOM object and you don't have to extract from the event.

Comment: I think the common denominator here is that there are multiple solutions.